# Issues connecting to Db2 from Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, db2

dsn_driver = "{IBM DB2 ODBC DRIVER}"

dsn_database = "BLUDB"            # e.g. "BLUDB"

dsn_port = "50000"                # e.g. "50000"

dsn_protocol = "TCPIP"            # i.e. "TCPIP"

%sql ibm_db_sa://usnername:password@Hostname:Port/Database

This is resulting in the following error:Connection info needed in SQLAlchemy format, example:

```
           postgresql://username:password@hostname/dbname
           or an existing connection: dict_keys([])Can't load plugin:sqlalchemy.dialects:ibm_db_saConnection info needed in SQLAlchemy format, example:
          postgresql://username:password@hostname/dbname
           or an existing connection: dict_keys([])
```

If anyone can please assist on this that would be great. My problem is that I am entering the service credentials correctly in the %sql ibm_db_sa line so not sure where I am going wrong or where the error can be corrected. Thank you

Answer (score -1):

You need to execute the `%load_ext sql` in order to enable SQL Magic in your notebook.